# Google Static Map not loading

Tags: php, sql, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am retrieving values from an SQL table to be displayed, and I want to display a static map using the latitude and longitude co-ordinates previously taken in.

```
<?php
if(isset($row["address"]))
{
    echo"<b>Address: </b>";
    echo $row["address"];
    echo "<br>";
}

$latitude = $row["latitude"];
$longitude = $row["longitude"];

$map = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=".$latitude.",".$longitude."&zoom=13&size=300x300&key=[my key goes here]";
?>

<img src="$map">
```

I have renewed the key and tested the link seperately, and it loads fine in a Chrome browser tab. However, when I try to load it through my webpage, the address section loads fine, but instead of a map there is the usual icon that shows the picture hasn't loaded. *(Not enough rep to post a picture of my actual output).*

This is my first time using the API so any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to reference $map variable outside the php code

You can try this

```
<?php
if(isset($row["address"]))
{
    echo"<b>Address: </b>";
    echo $row["address"];
    echo "<br>";
}

$latitude = $row["latitude"];
$longitude = $row["longitude"];

$map = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=".$latitude.",".$longitude."&zoom=13&size=300x300&key=[my key goes      here]";

echo '<img src="'. $map . '">'
?>
```